# Hive on spark Ambari 2.7.4

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I've set it up：

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark ;
set spark.master=yarn -cluster;
set mapreduce.job.queuename=ada.spark;
```

But when I use the hive command to enter, I execute SQL and report the following error:

```
select count(*) from dwd_tbl_ec_document where dt between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-03';
```

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line
> 1:0 cannot recognize input near     'Error' ':' 'Error'
> (state=42000,code=40000)

If I use beeline to execute this SQL, the execution is successful.